# Lack of available storage on my Samsung Galaxy Tablet

Tags: internal-storage

My samsung galaxy tablet is low on storage and i have no idea where the storage is being used.   When I go into setting and look up storage I get a reading for the various sources documents,apps,pictures, etc.  When I add up the usage I get about 5G.  The usaged defined on the tablet is 15G.  Where is the other 10G being consumed.  Cache has all been cleared so I know it is not that and that should have been in the 5G anyways.  Is it the operating system?

Comment: Welcome on the Android SE! If the user-level options are depleted, I think here is the time to think on rooting. Hopefully you will get an useful answer before that.

Comment: I suggest you to read the posts here about how storage works W-A-A-A-Y before you head into rooting. Rooting should not be undertaken lightly, and you'll need the knowledge anyway. Move slowly and with firm footing.